# pcap "undefined reference to" error

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

I'm trying to read in data from pcap files using pcap_open_offline(). I've used `#include <pcap/pcap.h>` and compiled with no errors after some debugging. Now I've come across another problem I can't seem to figure out. I wrote the following function:

```
void openPcap(char* filename){
  printf("Opening file %s\n", filename);
  pcap_t *pcap;
  const unsigned char *packet;
  char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
  struct pcap_pkthdr header;
  pcap = pcap_open_offline(filename, errbuf);
  if (pcap == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s Malformed packet records in file %s",ER,filename);
  }
}
```

And my pcap_open_offline call gives me about 100 of these errors when I try to compile:

```
pcap-linux.c:(.text+0xcd4): undefined reference to 'nl_handle_alloc'
pcap-linux.c:(.text+0xce8): undefined reference to 'genl_connect'
pcap-linux.c:(.text+0xcf6): undefined reference to 'genl_ctrl_alloc_cache'
pcap-linux.c:(.text+0xd0e): undefined reference to 'genl_ctrl_search_by_name'
pcap-linux.c:(.text+0xd64): undefined reference to 'nl_handle_destroy'
pcap-linux.c:(.text+0xdd7): undefined reference to 'nl_cache_free'
```

This is what my makefile looks like:

```
# -------------------------------
C=/afs/nd.edu/user14/csesoft/new/bin/gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c11 -I/afs/nd.edu/coursesp.18/cse/cse30341.01/support/gcc-libpcap/include -D_BSD_SOURCE
LD=/afs/nd.edu/user14/csesoft/new/bin/g++
#LD=g++
LDFLAGS=-lpthread
# # ----------------------------

LDFLAGS += -L/afs/nd.edu/coursesp.18/cse/cse30341.01/support/gcc-libpcap/lib -lpcap                 # Add your own flags here, or leave blank

threadedRE: threadedRE.o
    $(LD) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

threadedRE.o: threadedRE.c
    $(C) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

# C compiler
 %.o: %.c
    $(C) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f threadedRE *.o
```

And my headers are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <pcap/pcap.h>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a compiling error, but a linking one. At the end of build process you should see something like "ld exited with error".

`pcap_open_offline()` seems to use `nl_handle_alloc()` and other functions, but linker can't find object files containing their implementation. Pointing linker to proper library which contains required object files by adding `-lnl` to LDFLAGS should do the trick.

Comment: My TA had suggested that as well, but that didn't work. I ended up moving forward by just manually parsing the pcap files. Thank you for your help! Hopefully -lnl works for someone else who comes across this problem.